# Detecting the lines (structure edges) in a charcoal drawing image

Tags: python, image, opencv, line

I want to detect the all lines of a structure's edges but I can't detect every line. Does anyone know how to do that?

I want to detect lines in this picture but it's really noisy and I can't detect every line. I tried denoising, blurring and other things then I used canny line detection but it didn't find every line.

**Here is the original image:**

[image: original]

I want to detect every edge of those structures.
Can anyone do that?

**I got this with denoising:**

[image: I got]

My code:

```
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray_image,None,20)
blur_image = cv2.medianBlur(denoised,5)
cv2.imshow('blur_image 2',blur_image)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 40, 255)
cv2.imshow('canny_image',edges)

# Hough Transform 
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=10)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do division normalization (blur the image by a small amount then divide the image by the blurred image), then increase contrast.

Comment: Please show updated code and result when you have finished. You can change contrast with cv2.normalize() or I like skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity()

Comment: i couldnt do that can you help me with codes?

Comment: i did what u said but i got too noisy img how can i denoise it without lose the edges?

Comment: You can try thresholding and then get connected components and filter on size as one approach. You can try noise filtering after division normalization.

Comment: i tried to mask the division and i got [this](https://i.hizliresim.com/ldl0iko.jpg)

Comment: So is there a question?  Mask with what?

Comment: mask the gray pixels but i got noisy img how can i denoise that binary image

Comment: You can use connected components and filter on area or use contours and filter on area